# What options do I have for very compact or pancake lenses for full frame Sony E cameras?

Tags: lens, sony, full-frame, e-mount

I love tiny lenses, but I haven't found anything that is smaller than the Samyang 35mm 2.8 that also covers full frame for Sony's E-Mount. Is there any option I have that could make an a7r2 jacket pocketable? Manual focus is fine, it just needs to cover full frame and be tiny.

Comment: ***Is there any option I have that could make an a7r2 jacketpocketable?*** Buy a jacket with bigger pockets?

Comment: I was waiting for that one :D

Comment: Are pinholes on topic here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that sensors hate it if light hits them in all too angled a fashion, so short focal length lenses that are simply very close to the sensor and project light in a "wide funnel" fashion can create surprises (eg color vignettes or very bad corner performance).

The most radical option is using an 28mm or 35mm rangefinder or enlarger lens of true prime design (not retrofocal) on a short helicoid adapter (which makes it a partially collapsible lens) - but do expect said surprises, these setups border on the experimental.

The Agfa Ambion 35 f4.0 is interesting here (same that I used for a demonstration in [Do lenses affect color fidelity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20929/do-lenses-affect-color-fidelity) ... careful, that test shot is not full frame) - but difficult to adapt.

Comment: What kind of mount does that use? I have a 3D printer and could design an adapter for it, but I'm wondering about the necessary flange distance? I have a tiny russian M42 50mm 3.5 lens, but M42 requires a very long distance to the sensor, negating the size of the lens.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVnGW0GZewI This guy hacked an adapter, but it's so large that it's pointless.

Comment: Hard to make it shorter, flange distance comes into play, and rangefinder lenses like that already are among the shortest in that regard. Hacked my own adapter too: Drill an M42 body cap just right, press fit the lens, then screw onto M42 plumbing.

Comment: And... the Industar 50-2 can also be made into a semi-collapsing lens by using a helicoid instead of a fixed M42 adapter...